# Why is the positive terminal of the DC source connected to the primary of the transformer?

Tags: transformer, inverter

Why is the positive terminal of the DC source connected to the primary of the  transformer?

[image]

[Link to random inverter circuit I found online](http://www.circuitsgallery.com/2012/07/simple-low-power-inverter-6v-dc-to-230v.html)

Comment: I inserted the pic for you, now you should clean things up and make it into a decent question.

Comment: I don't know, but if I copy and paste the link after "enter lin description here" I get a scary result... Am I the only one who get this result?!?

Comment: The original push-pull output stage.

Comment: @next-hack *Pretty* sure that it was just an unintentional breaking of the link URL.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwJ307.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) SW1 conducting. (b) SW2 conducting.*

Figure 1 shows a simplified version of your inverter circuit with switches replacing the transistors.

- When SW1 is closed current flows through the centre-tap through SW1 inducing a voltage on the secondary as shown by the arrow.
- When SW1 is opened and SW2 is closed a similar current flows in the other half of the primary winding but note that the current direction in the coil has now been reversed. The induced voltage on the secondary is now also reversed.
- If this cycle is repeated the phase reversal on the secondary will generate alternating current, AC, which is the purpose of your circuit.

> Why positive terminal of dc source is connected to primary of transformer?

Because the transistor switches are connected to negative and a positive connection is the only way to get current to flow.

Comment: The current flow on the secondary side should be the opposite of the current flow on the primary side.

Comment: You are correct. Fixed, and I added the voltage indicators. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The **centertap** of the transformer is connected to the positive supply because this is a [push-pull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_converter) configuration.

It is a circuit which can make an AC voltage from a DC supply.

Only one of the two NMOS transistors is on at any time. When the upper NMOS is conducting (on) the lower one is off etc.

When the upper NMOS is conducting the current through the primary side of the transformer will introduce a magnetic flux in a certain direction. Then the upper NMOS is switched off while the lower is switched on. This causes the current in the primary side of the transformer to **reverse direction** and also the magnetic flux will **reverse direction**.

This introduces an AC voltage at the secondary side of the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Drain of the N-channel FET transistors are switching on and off by turn and pass a negative source to transformer.
That`s why a positive source is required as primary connected to transformer.